# При прокрутке страницы вниз, нужно анимировать картинки, например...

Tags: jquery

Например прозрачность у картинки 0, как блок поднимается выше, картинка начинала появляться. Подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оттолкнитесь от такого:

```
$(window).on('scroll resize touchmove', function(){

    var $this    = $(this),
        viewPort = $this.height(),          // высотка "вьюпорта"
        now      = $this.scrollTop(),       // положение курсора
        obj      = $('#pic').offset().top;  // оффсет картинки относительно window

    // console.log(viewPort + ' -> ' + now + ' -> ' + obj);

});
```

Вместо примера: http://jsfiddle.net/nJv29/